# Loop transfers data from last row only

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to transfer data from one sheet to another in format as shown in the pictures. The length of the data in sheet one is unknown. The code I am using will place the data in the proper format but all of the data ends up as the data from the last row.

```
For b = 1 To l - 1 Step 1
    For c = 0 To (l - 2) * 4 Step 4

        idvalue = Sheet1.Cells(b + 1, 1).Value
         Sheet3.Cells(c + 1, 2).Value = idvalue
        namevalue = Sheet1.Cells(b + 1, 2).Value
         Sheet3.Cells(c + 2, 2).Value = namevalue
        amountvalue = Sheet1.Cells(b + 1, 3).Value
         Sheet3.Cells(c + 3, 2).Value = amountvalue
        commentsvalue = Sheet1.Cells(b + 1, 4).Value
         Sheet3.Cells(c + 4, 2).Value = commentsvalue

    Next c
Next b
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try this code. A general solution that does not care about the size of your table and also you can use it always for any table to convert it to long format. https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/convert-crosstab-table-database-list-table-excel-vba-macro-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes the code a lot easier to read.

Obviously you'll also need to change the For loop declaration to whatever start row / end row is required.

```
Sub Example()

Dim lNewRow As Long
Dim lOldRow As Long

lNewRow = 1

For lOldRow = 2 To 7

    With Sheets("Sheet3")

        .Cells(lNewRow, 1) = "ID"
        .Cells(lNewRow, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lOldRow, 1)

        .Cells(lNewRow + 1, 1) = "NAME"
        .Cells(lNewRow + 1, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lOldRow, 2)

        .Cells(lNewRow + 2, 1) = "AMT"
        .Cells(lNewRow + 2, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lOldRow, 3)

        .Cells(lNewRow + 3, 1) = "COMMENTS"
        .Cells(lNewRow + 3, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lOldRow, 4)

    End With

    lNewRow = lNewRow + 4

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the question as answered using the tick.